# Keyboard and touchpad problems on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, touchpad

I recently made my laptop (ZenBook Pro 15 UX550GEX_UX580GE) a Win10 - Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot.
After successfully installing Ubuntu 20.04, I noticed that both my keyboard and touchpad are not working properly. When typing (on the internal keyboard), the letters appearing on the screen seem to lag for a moment every 10-15 characters or so. The touchpad has a similar issue, I cannot select text longer then about 15-20 characters for some reason.

I already tried `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`, but that did not help at all. I then did `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input all`, and re-installed the package, but that, too, did not help.

The issues may sound minor, but make typing and working on this laptop practically impossible. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall only `xserver-xorg-input-all` (if `xorg-input-evdev` package exists, uninstall that too) and install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.